# BeautifulSoup - find img with different extensions

Tags: python, django, regex, image, beautifulsoup

I'm working on a project in django and I have to find photos in the provided .csv file in `Text` column. The problem is that at this point I'm downloading only those with the `.jpg` extension. How to download e.g. those with the extension `.png` in one line, as follows:

I am using to this task BeautifulSoup.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(row['Text'], features="html5lib")
images = soup.findAll('img', src=re.compile('.jpg'))
```

**Edit:**
Below is example `Text` column in `.csv` file.

```
<wphimage data="{'FileId':6182,'Copyright':'John Smith','Alignment':'left','ZoomDisabled':false,'ImageOnly':false,'AlternativeText':'John Smith','ImageVersion':'conductorportraitlong','tabid':0,'moduleid':0}">
    <span style="display:block; float:left;" class="DIV_imageWrapper">
        <a data-lightview-title="Adela Frasineanu" data-lightview-caption="" class="lightview" href="//example.com/static/images/image.JPG">
                    <img src="//example.com/static/images/image.JPG" alt="John Smith">
                </a> 
               <a href="javascript:;">≡ <span>John Smith</span></a>
               <a class="A_zoom lightview" href="//example.com/static/images/image.JPG" data-lightview-title="John Smith" data-lightview-caption="">+ </a>
    </span>
</wphimage>
```

Comment: Add some examples of the Text column contents please.

Comment: @0buz Please check now.

Answer (score 0):

You could get all `src`s regardless of extension.

```
images = soup.find_all('img')
img_src=[img['src'] for img in images]
```

Answer (score 0):

you were almost there, try this:

```
images = soup.findAll('img', src=re.compile('.*\.png', re.IGNORECASE))
```